# How to get lock for files with tortoisesvn by providing a set of file paths

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, solidworks

We are planning to use SVN for Solidworks. Solidworks assembly will contain lot of other Sub-assemblies and parts from various paths. I now want control on a complete assembly, as we identify modules based on assemblies rather than folder paths. To do that i would like to give TortoiseSVN the paths of all the files included in the assembly (which i can get from solidworks references list) & i want TortoiseSVN to get lock for all those files. So that i don't need to go searching for 100s of paths and getting lock for them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a question here?  And is SVN going to be the best option?

Comment: I edited it to look like a question, thanks. We have got no other option from the office.

Comment: You may want to give it a try first @RaviTejaTadepalli!